# Can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my python code

Tags: python, debugging

```
[Python script][1]
```

Can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong here, for some reason can't seem to get all my outcomes to show. The idea is to stop asking the user for input once guesses are equal to 0, but when I play around with the code to try to fix it, it gives me other errors :(

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6GCH.png

Comment: Please provide your code as a text not an image and describe you problem further.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @Hussein  ```def number_guessing(guesses)```  define your function like that and pass a value

Comment: @iliya there is no need to use a parameter in a function. I think that the problem is that the variable guesses never changes.

Comment: remember to post your code as snippet and not as an image/link/text

Answer (score 2):

In the lines where you do

```
guesses - 1
```

you decrement the value of `guesses` by 1 but you are not assigning the result to a variable. What you need to do is:

```
guesses = guesses - 1
```

There is also [a shorter way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845498/50065) to write the same thing:

```
guesses  -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable is being decreased by 1 but it is not saving the new value. So, as @BioGeek answer, you have to update your variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have done the whole thing wrong "bud". You have written

```
if guesses <= 2
```

Which means that it will keep on continuing even if guesses has surpassed -1 million or something like that because it is less than two.

```
guesses = 2
def ask():
  ans = input("Enter the guess: ")
  if ans == "Booga":
    print("Correct")
    return True
  else:
      global guesses
      print("Incorrect")
      guesses = guesses - 1
      return False
while guesses != 0:
 n = ask()
 if n == True:
    break
 else:
    pass
```

This is a working example, your code is terribly wrong, your function already asks two times, which makes the guesses variable useless, also, use global keyword so that you can access the guesses variable, you also need to structure the if statements in a better way. I don't know if the current structure works or not as it's not in text form. Check for guesses not being zero else, end the code like:

```
if guesses != 0:
     #Do your thing
    g = input("Guess: ")
     if g == "Booga":
        #Success
    else:
         #Do your thing accordingly
else:
    print("Game over")
```