# what is the principle in dtype convertion in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Recentell I found a phononmen, let there is a int array named `data` whose value is

```
[[1,2,3],
[4,5,6]]
```

And I want to subtract a float and I wrote like below

```
data[0] = data[0] - 0.5
```

In my mind, `data` should be

```
[[0.5, 1.5, 2.5],
[  4,   5,   6]]
```

Actually, `data` doesn't change. And I use another way => `data[0] -= 0.5`, and there is a dtype error.

So, I use `astype` and make it work, but what confuse me is why `data[0] = data[0] - 0.5` doesn't cause error? What is the difference between `data[0] = data[0] - 0.5` and `data[0] -= 0.5`? I found [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845445/and-symbols-in-python/37845498) said it is equivalent.

Comment: dtype of an array does not change!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `data` was changed, you just ended up replacing some values with the same values. The expression `data[0] - 0.5` creates a new array allowed to have a new dtype, in this case a float dtype array `[0.5, 1.5, 2.5]`. However, `data` is an integer dtype array, and it can't change its dtype, even if you try to assign the float array `[0.5, 1.5, 2.5]` to a part of it `data[0]`. It ends up rounding to `[1, 2, 3]`, which happen to be the same values. Try `data[0] = data[0] - 1.5`, and you'll see a difference.

Second, the source that told you `x = x + y` is equivalent to `x += y` is wrong in Python. `x = x + y` does `x.__add__(y)` addition then `=` assignment. `x += y` is implemented by `x.__iadd__(y)`, a completely separate method. In most cases though, `__add__` and `__iadd__` will do very similar things.

Your case is further complicated by the indexing `data[0] -= 0.5` so `data.__setitem__(0, temp)` will be called after `temp = data[0].__isub__(0.5)`.