# Updating the same variable in an if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a multi-line `if` statement:

```
if period == 1:  
    var1 = 0  
else:  
    var1 *= OneExpression  
    var1 *= AnotherExpression  
    var1 *= EvenAnotherExpression
```

I do not really get what is happening with `var1`.
Is it like "var1 = first expression" and then "var1 = first expression times second expression" and so on? Or will it just get adjusted according to the code and in the end I only have the solution from `EvenAnotherExpression`?

I got what the operator does, I just did not get why it is drawing on var1 multiple times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [^=, -= and += symbols in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845445/and-symbols-in-python)

Comment: It's the same as `var1 = var1 * OneExpression * AnotherExpression * EvenAnotherExpression`.  If the "*" were not there, then it would be as you describe.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you!!

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. In the future, please try your own research first. Pick out individual pieces like `*=` and make sure you understand them before trying to understand the whole thing. Searching for symbols can be difficult, but Google worked in this case and found [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp). For other symbols, try [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/).

Answer (score 0):

var1 is multiplied multiple times in else statement. To understand it better, imagine this

```
var1 = 2 
OneExpression = 2 
AnotherExpression = 3
EvenAnotherExpression = 4
```

When the else statement is triggered, var1 is first multiplied with OneExpression. So 2 times 2 is equal to 4. 4 is now assigned to var1.

Then the second multiplication. var1, which is now 4, is multiplied by AnotherExpression, which is 3. So var1 is now equal to 12, because 4 times 3 equals to 12.

The last multiplication now comes. var1, which is now 12, is multiplied by EvenAnotherExpression, which is 4. So var is now 48, because 12 times 4 is 48.

You can check this by putting print(var1) below the last multiplication in the else statement.